# MIUI not detecting ".app" as a link on QR Code

Tags: android, qr-code, xiaomi, miui

I'm building an app that involves generating QR codes with a certain link (eg: mywebsite.app/cLKXz).

Everything works fine on stock android, Samsung, and Apple.
But MIUI's integrated scanner simply doesn't recognize a .app domain as a link, which causes the user to have to copy the text and paste it on their browser, instead of being able to simply tap "Open Link".

Is there any way I can "force" this QR Code to be detected as a link no matter what's inside? Of course I'd like to keep my domain and avoid using another URL shortener such as Bitly, if possible.

**EDIT**

I already tried adding http://, https://, and www., but nothing seems to work.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> mywebsite.app/cLKXz

Prefix your URL with protocol like `http://` or `https://`

Comment: Already did, forgot to mention it. Still nothing, same thing with www.

Comment: Then yo may not be able to do much as it looks they validate FQDN (which is extremely stupid, if true). Your only way to work that around (I assume that `foo.app` domain is yours) is to use other domain (`foo.com`) or any sort of redirector in recognizable domain (like `bit.ly` etc).

Answer (score -1):

It's a little late for the answer  but it's an issue of the native QR reader.

See: https://c.mi.com/oc/thread-3359510-1-0.html

Same problem occurs when using domains ending with:

- .cloud
- .link

Comment: can't open. showing invalid link.

Comment: Odd, I can access it without problems.
Problably because off the URL parameter

Try this one: https://c.mi.com/oc/thread-3359510-1-0.html